# Is there another outer-like function for multiple vectors in R

Tags: r

I have multiple vectors and I want to get all combinations of these vectors. Say, I have `v_1=(v_{1,1},...,v_{1,n_1}), ... , v_m=(v_{m_1,1},...,v_{m,n_m})` and I want to get the set of `u={(u_1,...,u_m)|u_i∈v_i}`. For 2 vectors, `outer` can do this job (needs reshape). How about the case of arbitrate number of vectors?

Comment: Reproducible examples are the way to go.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to actually address the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `?expand.grid`, which returns all the combinations in a data.frame. For example:

```
> expand.grid(1:3, 1:2, 1)
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    1    1    1
2    2    1    1
3    3    1    1
4    1    2    1
5    2    2    1
6    3    2    1
```

A more programmatic approach is to combine it with `do.call`:

```
do.call(expand.grid, list(1:3, 1:2, 1))
```

which gives you the same result.

Comment: If you supply expand.grid with a list, you do not need `do.call()`

Comment: interesting, was it always like this?

Comment: Looking at the manner in which the arguments start with a triple-dot form, I suspect so.

Comment: Hmm. I can think of many functions with ellipsis as the first argument (`c`, `sum`, `paste`, `save`) but none with  a similar `do.call` behavior when it is passed a list.

Comment: @flodel, if you look at the source code, it specifically deals with the case where you pass 1 argument in `...` and it is a list.

Comment: @flodel, I was just about to point out the same thing.  `if (nargs == 1L && is.list(a1 <- args[[1L]])) 
        nargs <- length(args <- a1)`

Comment: @DWin - I'll be interested whether your or my approach is what the OP wants.

Comment: @mnel and Ricardo, I was only debating DWin's comment that it is a common feature for functions with a similar synopsis; I think it is in fact quite the opposite. And mnel you are way off on your answer for once!

Comment: @mnel. The OP ask for a set of n-tuples. I was reasoning by analogy with the arguments to `ave`. The second formal argument is `...` which always trips me up since I forget that it needs `FUN=` for success. If you pass it a list for the second argument and use FUN, ... success.

Comment: @flodel -- perhaps. My answer might be to a question worded `a combination of all these vectors` not `all combinations of these vectors`. I must say my set theory notation ability is not what it should be.

Comment: @flodel it is relatively common: `interaction`, `ave`, and `data.frame` have exactly that behaviour. `sum`, `min`, `max` etc work analogously for vectors.

Answer (score 5):

While `expand.grid` gives an idiomatically `R` approach, an alternative is presented here.

You can use the `sets` package. This gives access to data structures and grammar of set theory  in R.

Given three vectors, you

```
library(sets)
a <- 1:2
b <- 3:4
d <- 5:6

# You can create `set` objects

as <- as.set(a)
bs <- as.set(b)
ds <- as.set(d)

as
## {1L, 2L}
```

To create the appropriate `n-tuples`, you can use `*`

```
as * bs *ds
## {((1L, 3L), 5L), ((1L, 3L), 6L), ((1L, 4L), 5L), ((1L, 4L), 6L), ((2L, 3L),
##  5L), ((2L, 3L), 6L), ((2L, 4L), 5L), ((2L, 4L), 6L)}
```

To do this programatically

```
 vecList <- list(a, b, d)
 ntuples <- Reduce(`*`,lapply(vecList, as.set))
```

and to coerce back regular vectors use `unlist` on each `set`

To create a matrix where each column are the elements of the n-tuple

```
sapply(ntuples,unlist)
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
## [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2
## [2,]    3    3    4    4    3    3    4    4
## [3,]    5    6    5    6    5    6    5    6
```

Comment: The `u` I meant is a set. Maybe "n-tuple" is a better description. Sorry for the ambiguity.